# Jenkins ignores the exit code 1 from Gradle run task

Tags: testing, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

- Jenkins 2.89.3
- Gradle 3.5

I'm running a build using a pipeline:

```groovy
node {
    try {
        stage('Fetch code') {

            echo 'Pulling the Code...'
            checkout scm: [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                           branches                         : [[name: '*/$GIT_CLOUD_BRANCH']],
                           browser                          : [$class: 'GitLab', repoUrl: cloudRepo, version: gitlabVersion],
                           doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                           submoduleCfg                     : [],
                           userRemoteConfigs                : scm.userRemoteConfigs]
        }
        wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1920x1080x24']) {
            dir('BUILD') {
                stage('Clean DB and old reports') {
                    sh '''chmod +x cleanup_old_reports.sh
                    ./cleanup_old_reports.sh $PWD/../../builds $BUILD_NUMBER'''
                }

                stage('Build the application') {
                    sh '''chmod +x application.sh
                    ./application.sh -P${PROJECT}'''
                }
                stage('Run tests') {
                    sh 'gradle clean run -P${PROJECT} -P${RUN_TYPE}'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Generate reports') {
            allure([includeProperties: false,
                    jdk              : '',
                    properties       : [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results          : [[path: 'ExaTAGS/TagsRunner/allure-results']]])
            archive 'catalina.log'
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        println "in catch currentBuild.result: " + currentBuild.result
        throw ex
    } finally {
        notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    }
}
```

The stage 'Run tests' executes a gradle task RUN. In a case if there are any failed tests the main method of test runner throws an exception and RUN task returns exit code 1.

But despite this stage is marked as FAILED, the whole build is SUCCESSFUL:

[image]

I believe that RUN task actually does not throw an exception, cause I do not see the output I make in catch block in the pipeline script. But it really returns exit code different from 0, why does Jenkins ignore it? And what is the appropriate way to force Jenkins fail the whole build if there are any of failed stages?

**UPDATE**

build.gradle file:

```groovy
group 'project'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'application'

def aspectjVersion = "1.8.7"

mainClassName = 'tags.runner.TestManager'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-javaagent:APP_HOME_PLACEHOLDER/lib/aspectjweaver-${aspectjVersion}.jar"]

dependencies {
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectjVersion}"
}

def weaver = configurations.compile.find { it.name.contains("aspectjweaver") }

run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = jvmArgs << "-javaagent:$weaver"

        if (project.hasProperty('cloud')) {
            args("cloud")
        }
    }
}
```

And the main method of TestManager.
runTests() throws the **TestException** if the count of failed tests is more than 0:

```groovy
class TestManager {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            runTests()
        } catch (TestException ex) {
            throw ex
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.in.read()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `set -e` at the beginning of the jenkins script?

Comment: Could you please post your build.gradle file? Did you set ignoreErrors = true in there? It could be that the java process that is exited is not the Gradle process, but the surefire process spawned by Gradle.

Comment: I added the build file, and also I searched for ignoreErrors at the whole project and didn't find this.

Comment: I can't understand why Jenkins ignores the FAILED flag despite the fact that it is explicitly displayed in the log

Comment: Hello , it is not clear ti me - do you try to catch the error failure?

Comment: The thrown exception is expected and needed, if there is at least one test failed. But the exception does not appear in the catch block of the pipeline...

Comment: I mean, If tests throw TestException  I throw it to the gradle task and as displayed in the output log, it really fails the task. But for some reason this exception does not appear in pipeline's catch block and Jenkins does not see the failed task's status.